# Request retransmission until I get expected response (loop controller + timer case)

Tags: jmeter

I do request retransmission until I get the expected response.

I need to send one request and from the response, need to check the value of this one variable and if the response is not matching, then I need to send the same request again until I get the expected response.

On this case, I need to stop to request re-sending after some time, say two minutes. After two minutes, if I didn't get the proper response, then the request needs to stop being re-transmitted.

Please let me know how simulate this **(loop controller + timer case)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather go for [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) instead of the Loop Controller as in case of the While Controller you will be able to exit the loop earlier than 2 minutes in case if the response does match the expected value.

For instance the following function specified in the While Controller:

```
${__javaScript("${yourVar}"!="foo",)}
```

will trigger While Controller's children to run until `${yourVar}` value won't become `foo`, something like:

[image: While Controller Demo]

[__javaScript()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function is required in order to evaluate and compare variables as While Controller (unlike [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie)) doesn't treat the input as JavaScript so you need to pass the function explicitly.

Duration of the retrying logic can be set using [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) which basically defines for how long its children are allowed to run.